# How to read binary key in Python Cryptography?

Tags: python, python-cryptography

I have an RSA modulus and exponent in binary format. I don't have access to the key in PEM format. How can I load it using `cryptography` library?

I am not sure how to approach this but I have:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

key_file = open("key", "rb")
private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    base64.b64encode(key_file.read()),
    password=None,
    backend=default_backend()
)

ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.
```

As a note, I don't have to use the `cryptography` library and if there is a better way to do this using a different library, that's okay.

Comment: FYI, as pointed out in [the docs](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/) you should be very careful using things from the `cryptography.hazmat` submodule as doing things incorrectly can in the best case break your program, and in the worst case appear to work but completely break the security offered by encryption.

Comment: Do you have any idea what specific "binary format" the key is in? There's more than one.

Comment: No idea. Could be the concatenation `n` and `d`.

Comment: I also know that is 68 bytes long.

Comment: As a side note: in a typical computer all formats are binary.

Comment: Hi, may be your binary format is RSARef ? As used in the RSAEuro project https://github.com/mort666/RSAEuro ?